# List of groups returns empty after validation - Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-rest-framework

I tried several ways to make this work and I couldn't.

It is very likely, because I believe it should be working. I may be missing something that I am not aware of.

I thank you for your attention.

request.data

```
{
  "first_name": "Marcelo",
  "last_name": "Wanderley",
  "username": "marcelo",
  "cpf": "1234",
  "telefone": "99999999",
  "email": "marceloa@teste.com",
  "observacao": "",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 4
    }
  ],
  "password": "111111",
  "password_again": "111111",
  "token_user_chain": "TMWTIeGs2t1YPpKke2RZh2tLVMuMWdLFxaFYdD",
  "private_key": ""
}
```

> 'groups': [{'id': 2},{'id': 4}]

View

```
 if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.create(validated_data=serializer.validated_data)
     return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
 return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Model

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id',)


class serializerUser(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    id                  = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    first_name          = serializers.CharField()
    last_name           = serializers.CharField()
    email               = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    cpf                 = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    token_user_chain    = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    telefone            = serializers.CharField()
    groups              = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    observacao          = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    password            = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    username            = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    password_again      = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

Output Print

> OrderedDict([('first_name', 'Marcelo'), ('last_name', 'Wanderley'),
> ('email', 'marcelo@teste.com'), ('cpf', '123'), ('token_user_chain',
> 'TMWTIeGs2vpH7DGCYNiSCttdirrMqPFEgPnczA'), ('telefone', '999999'),
> ('groups', [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()]), ('observacao', ''),
> ('password', '999999'), ('username', 'Marcelo Wanderley'),
> ('password_again', '999999')])
>
> ('groups', [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()])

Comment: see doc [Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I went through the source codes, and maybe got the cause. Because it has a nested serializer, so it will exclude id field which not in _writable_fields when calling run_validation(). then return a empty OrderedDict instance.

if keep using nested serializer in order to creating instances of manytomany relation model.

```
groups_data = request.data.pop('groups')
if serializer.is_valid():
  instance = serializer.create(validated_data=serializer.validated_data)
  groups = [Group.objects.create(**kwargs) for kwargs in groups_data] #NOQA
  instance.groups.set(groups)
  instance.save()
  return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

OR if do not need to create new instances of related model, it could use the default ManyRelatedField rather than nested serializer. request.data['groups'] is just a list of id value:

```
groups: [
  1,
  2
]
```

Comment: perfect. I will test. Thank you friend.